# how to draw a line on an encoded image in bb?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, drawing

I want to draw a line on the encoded image so I will get a new image. Can you please give me information about that if you want ?
Thank you very much.
Here I give my code that I got the encoded image.

```
String URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
        + centerX + "," + centerY + "&zoom=15&size=480x320&"
        + "path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5" + path 
        + "&maptype=roadmap&sensor=true;deviceside=true";

            try {
                conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(URL);
                stream = conn.openInputStream();
                byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int dataToWrite = 0;
                while ((dataToWrite = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    byteArray.write(dataToWrite);
                }
                byte[] bArray = byteArray.toByteArray();
                EncodedImage image = 
                    EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(bArray, 0, bArray.length);
                imageBitmap = image.getBitmap();
                vfm.deleteAll();
                bitField = new BitmapField(imageBitmap);
                vfm.add(bitField);
```

Comment: You may have already considered this, but please note that Google's  Static Maps API explicitly disallows displaying static maps outside of a web browser unless you are a Google Maps API Premier customer: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a `Graphics` object

   ```
   Graphics graphics = new Graphics(imageBitmap);
   ```
2. Invoke `Graphics.drawLine()` to draw line on that bitmap.

   ```
   graphics.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
   ```

Now imageBitmap is a new bitmap with line.

Comment: or, in BB 4.7+ where constructor is deprecated, use `Graphics.create(imageBitmap)` instead.